# Bind WPF Pie-Chart to sql server

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pie-chart

I have created a Pie-chart using WPF Toolkit.
I have to extract the values for Ram Usage from my database table.
At my MainWindow.xaml.cs I have created a DB connection string to establish a database connectivity as follows :

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter da_Ram=null;
    DataSet ds_Ram = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
         con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=User212;Initial Catalog=UsageDB;Persist Security Info=True);
         con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void myChart1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectStatement = "select * from Used,Total from UsageDB.dbo.RamUsage";
        da_Ram = new SqlDataAdapter(selectStatement, con);
        ds_Ram = new DataSet();
        // I am stuck here to proceed for filling my Dataset
    }
```

}
}

XAML code :

```
   <loc1:Chart Name="myChart1" Background="YellowGreen" Foreground="DarkBlue" 
     Title="Ram Usage - Pie Chart" LegendTitle="Usage Details" Loaded="myChart1_Loaded" Margin="26,12,12,12">
   <loc1:PieSeries Title="Ram Usage" ItemsSource="{Binding RamUsage}"
               IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Total}"
               DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Used}">
    </loc1:PieSeries>
  </loc1:Chart>
```

Is this approach correct ? or do I have to create a separate class for retrieving the values from the datasource ? Thanks.

Comment: A very good tutorial over this topic is..http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28098/A-WPF-Pie-Chart-with-Data-Binding-Support .See it and learn how to do the work.

Comment: Thank you. I have already gone through this tutorial but they have binded the data from a collections. But I would like to bind it with the ms sql server DB

Comment: Create some C# classes which have the same properties as the tables in the database. Then bind your chart to the collection of those objects.

Comment: Do I have to create collectionclass and then use "get,set" for declaring the properties ? here my properties are **Total** and **Used**

Comment: @vorrtex I have created a ViewModel for my [RamUsage](https://gist.github.com/cd9a276b47253acaf6c2). could you please guide me how to procedd further for getting the data from the database.

Comment: @userXemY You need to read data from your `ds_Ram` dataset, create a while-loop, read next row and create an instance of RamViewModel on each iteration. I've never worked with data sets so I can't write exact code.